# Form data object is not formed on first click when validation fails; only on second click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I'm using a pretty simple form to submit something to our API. I added some form validation using a directive called [Angular UI Form Validation.](https://github.com/nelsonomuto/angular-ui-form-validation) I'm just submitting an object with 2 properties; 'id', and 'points'. I'm running into a strange issue that I've been having a lot of trouble solving and hope I can get some help here.

The form validation works fine. If I enter a value into the input field that doesn't pass, you can't submit the form and a message beneath the input saying why appears. However, if I then remove the incorrect input and put in a correct input, the message is still there. If I click on the submit button, the message disappears. If I click the submit button again, it submits. I've noticed, however, that if I just press the enter key it submits right away.

I threw some console.log's in there, and it looks like the problem is that a formData object isn't created on the first click; only on the second. Here is the html:

```
<form name="pointsField">
    <p><input type="number" ng-model="formData.points"
        validation-only-numbers="true"
        validation-field-required="{message:'Points value is required.',value:true}"
        min="0"/></p>
    <p><button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="updatePoints(pointsField)" ng-disabled="loading">
        <span ng-if="loading"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-la fa-spin"></i></span>Update Points
    </button></p>
</form>
```

And here is the Javascript (keep in mind that the formData object is created when the controller is initialized, and it is just an empty object):

```
    $scope.updatePoints = function(formData) {
        console.log('formData ', formData);
        $scope.$broadcast('runCustomValidations');
        if(formData.$invalid){
            return;
        }
        var pointsObject = {
            "id": $scope.userId,
            "points": $scope.formData.points
        };
        $scope.loading = true;
        User.updateUserPoints(pointsObject).then(function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
                Notification.now.success(response.message);
                $scope.loading = false;
            } else {
                Notification.now.error(response.message);
                $scope.loading = false;
            }
        }, function(reason) {
            Notification.now.error(reason.message);
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };
```

If anyone can help me out I'd be eternally grateful. Thank you!

Comment: try adding `$scope.apply()`

Comment: Where at? I don't think I've ever used it before.

Comment: at  ` $scope.updatePoints` 1st line and see if it works

Comment: No luck. I get an error saying '$apply is already in progress'.

Answer (score 2):

try adding `novalidate` in your form tag  if this does not work dont use angular ui Form validation just use below format to validate .

```
<form name="pointsField" novalidate>

   <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Email Address"
                   ng-model="user.username" autocomplete="off" required >
   <span class="text-danger" ng-show="pointsField.username.$dirty && pointsField.username.$invalid">
                    <span ng-show="pointsField.username.$error.required">Email Address is required</span>
                  </span>


    <button type="submit" class="submit center" ng-disabled="pointsField.$invalid || dataLoading ">

<form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I have it figured out, and it looks like it's a really annoying CSS problem. I've noticed that if I click on the top portion of the button it submits fine the first time. It's as if the error message is pushing down the clickable area of the button.